# Concatenating strings while passing as argument to function

Tags: c, string

There is a function that takes string as a parameter/argument.

```
Func(char* strA)
{
...
}
```

I have two strings;

```
#define FIRST "first"
char efg[] = " second";
```

I want to basically send `"first second"` as argument to `Func(strA)`, but I do not want to use `strcat(FIRST, efg);` as it would permanently change my macro `FIRST`.

Is there a way to send `"first second"` as argument without upsetting the macro above?

Comment: `char efg[] = {" second"};` is incorrect. It should be `char efg[] = " second";`

Comment: @Pubby: Why? Either is perfectly valid C.

Comment: @R.. Oh, I didn't realize. Nevermind then.

Comment: @Sunny you can check my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use of sprintf function to write first in a temp buffer:

```
#define FIRST "first"
char efg[] = " second";  
char* space = " ";
char* strA = calloc(strlen(FIRST) + strlen(space) + strlen(efg) + 1, sizeof(char));  

sprintf(strA,"%s%s%s",FIRST, space, efg);

Func(strA);  

free(strA);
```

Give it a Try!!

---

Note: don't forget free() dynamic allocated memory.

Description:
The `sprintf()` function is just like `printf()`, except that the output is sent to buffer. The return value is the number of characters written.

Comment: @R.. I was sure you were going to be the first one to point that out.

Comment: Well it's safe as-is (aside from failure to check the return value of `calloc` for success, and wrong number of arguments to `calloc`), since the space needed is correctly computed, but it would be nice to use `snprintf` anyway.

Comment: Also OP should be aware that the buffer needs to be freed at some point.

Comment: Another small improvement: don't cast the return value of `calloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's permissable to you not to have `efg` as a variable but as a string literal, then because adjacent string literals are implicitly concatenated (spec C99: 5.1.1.2.6) you could simply have the following:

```
Func(FIRST " second");
```

And for the same reason you could alternatively declare `efg` as

```
char efg[] = FIRST " second";
```

Either way, much easier than strcat or sprintf.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can first copy your macro to a new char array using `strcpy()`, then `strcat( new_var, efg )` - pass that as parameter.